# Magento 2.2.2 Migrate site in another server. Points to look out

Tags: migration, magento2.2.2

We are planning to transfer out test site to the production server.

What must we look out for? What changes ought to be made?

Comment: So are you going to move site to different server then the current test site  server or just want to change test domain to live domain/production ?

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements2.html

Comment: I want to move the site to a different server.

Comment: Can you tell me which OS is set in your new server ?

Comment: New server will be probably UBUNTU :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **UBUNTU/LINUX operating system** follow below steps.

> Step:1  **apache/server** settings

Run below commands in your server

```
sudo a2enmod expires
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Now change apache configuration. in **apache2.conf** file.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

    <Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
  <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

now after changes you should restart apache.

```
run sudo service apache2 restart
```

change magento permission according to system user.

----Apply permission to directory only------

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

----Apply permission to files only------

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

> step: 2 **Magento** settings

1. change  website mode from current to production mode, before you change mode just compile your current code

   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
2. after success , you can change website mode

   php bin/magento setup:deploy:mode:production
3. Set Default Robots "index,follow."

**Magento 2.1.* and older version:**

```
Go to Store -> configuration -> general ->  design ->Search Engine Robots tab and then select 'index,follow'.
```

**Magento 2.2.*:**

```
Go to Content -> configuration -> select/edit website row -> Search Engine Robots tab and then select 'index,follow'.
```

4. add Google analytics related settings and code.
5. create site-map.
6. set magento cron.
7. merge minify css and js from configuration
8. enable all Magento cache.
9. Admin url and password must need to be difficult.

   10.set email sending configuration

**Note: Take database backup daily. :)**

Comment: That was a great write up. Impressive work sir. One question: What should I look out if my current setup is on a windows server?

Comment: Nothing to worry , just create source code zip from your current system and extract in new server, after follow above steps.

Comment: Awesome! You were very helpful. I would also point out, to change the base urls in the `core_config_data` table at the magento database. Do you know where else should I make similar changes? Maybe .htaccess?

Comment: yes I forget to mention database changes in above list , yes you need to change in .htaccess regarding page speed up changes.

Comment: if  this answer is helpful to you then please approve and up-vote answer so it will be helpful to others also.

Comment: What changes need to be made in htaccess? You were very helpful, I am upvoting but my reputation is 11 and my upvote is not visible yet.

Comment: we have mentioned in our note, please follow it. we have described all settings.